# Erro "Doesn't have a default value" ao tentar inserir dados no DB

Tags: php, mysql

Estava a tentar inserir as variáveis que recebi de um formulário, quando recebi esta mensagem de erro:

> 'nidcrespons1' doesn't have a default value

Meu código:

```
<?php
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "vertrigo", "winit");
    $nomeempresa = $_POST["nomeempresa"];
    $paisempresa = $_POST["paisempresa"];
    $moradaempresa = $_POST["moradaempresa"];
    $nifempresa = $_POST["nifempresa"];
    $crc = $_POST["crc"];
    $telefoneempresa = $_POST["telefoneempresa"];
    $respons1 = $_POST["respons1"];
    $nidcrespons1 = $_POST["nidcrespons1"];
    $nifrespons1 = $_POST["nifrespons1"];
    $emailempresa = $_POST["emailempresa"];
    $senhaempresa = $_POST["senhaempresa"];

    echo $nomeempresa;
    echo $paisempresa;

    $insere = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO empresas (nomeempresa, respons1) VALUES ('$nomeempresa', '$respons1')") or die(mysqli_error($link));
?>
```

Comment: Passa um valor p ele, deve vir do form, faça isso para todas as colunas.

Comment: O problema é esse mesmo, coloca isso como resposta para eu dar pontuação.

Comment: Você pode criar um resposta :)

Comment: Não tem a ver com a pergunta, mas fica a dica: use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) no seu código SQL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O problema é que você tem que passar algum valor para as colunas do banco de dados que são `NOT NULL`, a coluna não pode estar sem nada, ou seja o `INSERT` tem que ter algo, para preencher a coluna.